# Aggregate multiple count responses from Mongo DB

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have migrated my code from Postgres to Mongo. In Postgres, I have used a hql query to fetch counts of same object in multiple dimensions in the same query. I am trying to achieve the same with mongo so that the number of calls to the database is reduced. I am using Spring-Data-MongoDB here.

My Document Looks like below.

```
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task {
    @Id
    String id;

    @Field(name = "name")
    String name;

    String size;

    String tag;
}
```

My SQL Query is something like this

```
@Query(value = "select ta as tag, count(CASE WHEN t.size='S' THEN 1 END) as countS, count(CASE WHEN t.size='M' THEN 1 END) as countM, count(CASE WHEN t.size='L' THEN 1 END) as countL, count(CASE WHEN t.size='XL' THEN 1 END) as countXL from Tag ta left join UserTag ut on ta=ut.tag left join Task t on t.tag=ut.tag where ut.user=?4 and upper(ta.company)=?5 group by ta")
```

The above query returns me a Projection

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class TagCountProjection {
    public String tag;

    public int countS;

    public int countM;

    public int countL;

    public int countXL;
}
```

I am trying to replicate the same with Spring-Data-Mongo instead of Spring-Data-JPA.

`int countByTagIgnoreCaseAndSize(String tag,String size);`

But this just returns the response for 1 tag. I am looking to group by and fetch. With lot of searches, i tried to arrive at the below code, still no luck with what i exactly wanted to achieve.

```
public List<TagCountProjection> getTodoCounts(String countVariable) {
GroupOperation agg = group("tag").count()
                .as(new StringBuilder().append("count").append(countVariable).toString());
        MatchOperation filter = match(new Criteria("size").is(countVariable));
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filter, agg);
        AggregationResults<TagCountProjection> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Task.class,
                TagCountProjection.class);
......
}
```

The above code again has to be called 4 times for each size so that i can consolidate the result. I still have 5-6 more fields to fetch this way, so i might end up in making 10 db calls for 1 api call, which is not a good practice. How do we conver the above sql to fit into this place?

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregation pipeline should do roughly what you want, though I'm not quite sure if this is your exact data structure, if it's vastly different please do let me know and I can take another look.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/xFUTG_sgRsH

I don't have enough experience with Spring to help you there but I'm hopeful with this you would be able to convert it into code yourself.

```js
db.UserTag.aggregate([
  { // match user
    $match: {
      user: 2
    }
  },
  { // lookup each of the users tags from the tag collection
    $lookup: {
      from: "Tag",
      localField: "tag",
      foreignField: "tag",
      as: "tags"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  { // group by the tag and size, sum results
    $group: {
      _id: {
        tag: "$tags.tag",
        size: "$tags.size"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      // group just by tag, send sizes into an array with their counts
      // can hardcode this to just extract the 4 types of course
      _id: "$_id.tag",
      sizes: {
        $push: {
          size: "$_id.size",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```js
// collections
db={
  Tag: [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "task",
      "size": "m",
      "tag": "tag1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "task",
      "size": "m",
      "tag": "tag1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "task",
      "size": "s",
      "tag": "tag1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "task",
      "size": "s",
      "tag": "tag2"
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "name": "task",
      "size": "xl",
      "tag": "tag1"
    }
  ],
  UserTag: [
    {
      user: 1,
      tag: "tag1"
    },
    {
      user: 2,
      // pipeline doesn't care if a user has multiple tags
      tag: [
        "tag2",
        "tag1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// output
[
  {
    "_id": "tag2",
    "sizes": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "size": "s"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "tag1",
    "sizes": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "size": "s"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "size": "xl"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "size": "m"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```